# Pass var from selected TableView Cell Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a beginner in Swift (Xcode) and I need help. I have a tableview and I want to send information from the indexPath.row to a segue.

My script work, but the problem is the data send to my segue is the previous selected row and not the current cell select. Because the function prepare segue is called before the func tableView. That's make 2 days I search and every tutorial give me the same problem.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    jobname = filldata[indexPath.row]
    print(jobname)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "jobsegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "jobsegue" {
        let destVC = segue.destination as! JobNameViewController
        destVC.jobname = jobname
    }
}
```

Thank you sooo much for your help!

Comment: it seems ok ...  it should work ...

Comment: By any chance, do you have the segue also defined in a storyboard?  That's the only way that I can think of to make `prepare` fire first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work fine:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "jobsegue", sender: indexPath.row)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "jobsegue" {
        let destVC = segue.destination as! JobNameViewController
        destVC.jobname = filldata[sender]
    }
}
```